# App crashes when trying to create a SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite

My app keep crashing when I try to add a new row to a table (which then calls `onCreate` because it doesn't exist yet). Line 40 is `db.execSQL(CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE_QUERY);`

My assumption so far is that there is something wrong with the query string, but I can't figure out what it is.

This is the class that manages the database:

```java
public class PBMDatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int database_version = 1;

    private String CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE_TABLE " + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_SESSION_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_STAKE_LEVEL + " TEXT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_LIMIT_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_GAME_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION + " TEXT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME + " TEXT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME + " TEXT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_BUY_IN + " INT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_CASH_OUT + " INT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_NUM_OF_PLAYERS + " INT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_POSITION_PLACED + " INT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_PLACES_PAID + " INT, "
            + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_IS_COMPLETED + " INT"
            + ");";


    public PBMDatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, PBMDatabaseContract.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Database created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Table created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void putNewCashGame(PBMDatabaseOperations dbop, String stake, String limit, String gameType, String location, String startTime, int buyIn){

        SQLiteDatabase sqdb = dbop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_STAKE_LEVEL, stake);
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_LIMIT_TYPE, limit);
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_GAME_TYPE, gameType);
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_LOCATION, location);
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME, startTime);
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_BUY_IN, buyIn);
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_CASH_OUT, 0);
        cv.put(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.COLUMN_NAME_IS_COMPLETED, 0);

        long k = sqdb.insert(PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("Database operations", "new row inserted to table " + PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.TABLE_NAME);

    }
}
```

This is the method that is calling the method to add a new row:

```java
createSession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (buyIn.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "The Buy In Field Cannot Be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Session cg = new Session();
            cg.setStakeLevel(stakes.getSelectedItem().toString());
            cg.setLimitType(limitTypes.getSelectedItem().toString());
            cg.setGameType(gameTypes.getSelectedItem().toString());
            //TODO Location is currently a string needs to be a Location Object
            //cg.setLocationName(locations.getSelectedItem().toString());
            cg.setStartTime(startDate.getText().toString());
            cg.setBuyIn(Integer.parseInt(buyIn.getText().toString()));

            //add to database
            PBMDatabaseOperations db = new PBMDatabaseOperations(C);
            db.putNewCashGame(db, cg.getStakeLevel(), cg.getLimitType(), cg.getGameType(),locations.getSelectedItem().toString(), cg.getStartTime(), cg.getBuyIn());
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "New Cash Game Session Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

and this is the logcat when I try to run it:

```
07-15 14:45:19.531    7107-7107/pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager D/Database operations﹕ Database created
07-15 14:45:19.534    7107-7107/pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "CREATE_TABLE": syntax error
07-15 14:45:19.535    7107-7107/pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-15 14:45:19.535    7107-7107/pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager, PID: 7107
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE_TABLE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE_TABLE sessions(id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, session_type TEXT, stake_level TEXT, limit_type TEXT, game_type TEXT, location TEXT, start_time TEXT, end_time TEXT, buy_in INT, cash_out INT, num_of_players INT, position_placed INT, places_paid INT, is_completed INT);
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
            at pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.PBMDatabaseOperations.onCreate(PBMDatabaseOperations.java:40)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.PBMDatabaseOperations.putNewCashGame(PBMDatabaseOperations.java:51)
            at pokerbankrollmanager.com.pokerbankrollmanager.AddCashGame$2.onClick(AddCashGame.java:183)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5199)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21155)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the word `CREATE_TABLE` when it should be two words `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE_TABLE " for` 
    CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 0):

From the stack,I guess the space is missing between the table name and the ( brace.

> CREATE_TABLE **sessions(id** INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, session_type
>   TEXT, stake_level TEXT, limit_type TEXT, game_type TEXT, location
>   TEXT, start_time TEXT, end_time TEXT, buy_in INT, cash_out INT,
>   num_of_players INT, position_placed INT, places_paid INT, is_completed
>   INT);

Use the following code:

```
private String CREATE_SESSIONS_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE_TABLE " + 
PBMDatabaseContract.SessionTable.TABLE_NAME + " ("
```

Comment: @yitzih oops...yes instead of using CREATE_TABLE using CREATE TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Try "create table" instead of "create_table".